# Magento Send Transaction Email Template to PDF as Attachment

Tags: magento-1.9, php, pdf, transactional-mail, zend-framework

I can successfully send email with Transaction Email Template but i am not able to convert Transaction Email Template into pdf and send it as attachment in the same email.

Any one can help to convert Transaction Email Template into pdf and send as attachment.

Here is complete code.

```
<?php require_once('app/Mage.php'); Mage::app();

    $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
    $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');
    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('Shipment-Alert');       


                     $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending', 'processing')))
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

                    foreach ($orders as $order) {

                    echo $order->getId();

                    echo $order->getIncrementId();
                    echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
                    echo $order -> getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
                    echo $order -> getShippingAddress()->getStreetFull();
                    echo $order -> getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
                    echo $order -> getShippingAddress()->getCity();
                    echo $order -> getCreatedAt();


                    $orderdetails = Mage::getmodel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('order_id', array('in' => array($order -> getId())));

                        foreach ($orderdetails as $orderdetail) {

                        echo $orderdetail -> getProductId();
                        echo $orderdetail->getName();
                        echo $orderdetail->getQtyOrdered();

                        $productmodel = Mage::getmodel('catalog/product')
                                                ->load($orderdetail -> getProductId());
                        echo $productmodel -> getData('creator_id');
                        echo "<br>";

                        $customers = Mage::getmodel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array($productmodel -> getData('creator_id'))));


                            foreach ($customers as $customer) {

                            echo $customer -> getData('entity_id');

                            echo $customer -> getEmail();                               
                            echo "<br>";

                            $emailTemplateVariables = array();
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] = $orderdetail->getProductId();
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] = $orderdetail->getName();    
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar4'] = $orderdetail->getQtyOrdered();  
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar5'] = $productmodel->getData('creator_id');   
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar6'] = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName(); 
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar7'] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();   
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar8'] = $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreetFull();  
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar9'] = $order -> getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();  
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar10'] = $order -> getShippingAddress()->getCity(); 
                            $emailTemplateVariables['myvar11'] = $order -> getCreatedAt();

                            $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

                            $emailTemplate->setSenderName('Shipment');
                            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($senderEmail);
                            $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject("Shipment Alert");

            // ---------------This below part is not working ---------------

                        if (!empty($pdf_attachment) && file_exists($pdf_attachment)) {
                                $emailTemplate
                                    ->getMail()
                                    ->createAttachment(
                                        file_get_contents(Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('Shipment-Alert')),
                                        Zend_Mime::TYPE_HTML,
                                        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                                        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                                        basename($emailTemplateVariables)
                                    );
                            } 
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            $emailTemplate->send('test@test', 'Shipment', $emailTemplateVariables);

                            }   
                    }
                }


    ?>
```

Comment: If you're looking for a solution to send orders / invoices as a pdf attachment, this extension might help: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/email-attachments-by-fooman.html

Comment: Why you want to attach the same email as pdf?